# Use values from one DataFrame to keep values from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created two dataframes, lets call them, `df1` `df2` where

```
print(df1)
                a                  b
1        0.375241                1.0
2             NaN                2.0
3        0.448792                3.0
4             NaN                4.0

df1 = df1[np.isfinite(df1['a'])]
print(df1)
                a                  b
1        0.375241                1.0
3        0.448792                3.0


print(df2)
          aa           bb
1   0.047606          1.0
2   0.202927          1.0
3   0.205663          1.0
4        NaN          1.0
5   1.388080          1.0
6   0.097084          1.0
7   0.136873          1.0 
8        NaN          1.0
9        NaN          1.0
10       NaN          1.0
12  0.084676          2.0
13  0.236850          2.0
14  0.532835          2.0
15       NaN          2.0
16       NaN          2.0
17  0.035106          2.0
18       NaN          2.0
19       NaN          2.0
20       NaN          2.0
22  0.419956          3.0
23  0.267132          3.0
24  0.944217          3.0
25  0.403024          3.0
26       NaN          3.0
27  0.184425          3.0
28  0.473998          3.0
29       NaN          3.0
30       NaN          3.0
31       NaN          3.0
33  0.465454          4.0
34  0.240867          4.0
35       NaN          4.0
36       NaN          4.0
37  0.323195          4.0
38  0.193764          4.0
39       NaN          4.0
40       NaN          4.0
41       NaN          4.0
42       NaN          4.0
```

based on the results from `df1['b']` where I only have 1 & 3 as valid numbers now, how would I go about keeping `df2['bb']` 1 & 3, and setting all other values in `df2` to np.nan so that this would be the final product

```
df2 = df2[np.isfinite(df2['aa'])]
print(df2)
          aa           bb
1   0.047606          1.0
2   0.202927          1.0
3   0.205663          1.0
5   1.388080          1.0
6   0.097084          1.0
7   0.136873          1.0 
22  0.419956          3.0
23  0.267132          3.0
24  0.944217          3.0
25  0.403024          3.0
27  0.184425          3.0
28  0.473998          3.0
```

Comment: Using `isin` df2.loc[df2.bb.isin(df1.bb),:]

Comment: Thanks for the help.with the `isin`. I believe you typed an extra b in their, so it wound up being `df2.loc[df2.bb.isin(df1.b),:]`. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, that is typo , :-) Yw, happy coding